# How to modify a particular div of ng repeat based on json value in angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a drop down,when I change the drop down option to cities,state..I am populating the values from json.Here my requirement is when I populate the value 'No data' on change of dropdown,that time button should hide for particular value only.Here is the code below.

### HTML

```
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select class="change" ng-model="x" ng-change="update()">
      <option value="city">Cities</option>
      <option value="state">States</option>
      <option value="country">Countries</option>
    </select>
    <div ng-repeat="emp in groups" class="test" ng-attr-id="{{emp[attr]}}">
    <p>{{emp[attr]}}<button ng-if="emp[attr]!='No data'" type="button">My button</button></p></div>
    <div ng-if="emp[attr]=='No data'">No db found</div>
  </div>
  </div>
```

### script

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.groups = [{
      title: 'title1',
      name: 'name1',
      details: 'No data',
      id : 1
    },
    {
      title: 'No data',
      name: 'name2',
      details: 'two',
      id : 2
    },
    {
      title: 'title3',
      name: 'name2',
      details: 'three',
      id : 3
    }
  ]
  $scope.update = function() {
    if ($scope.x == 'city') {
      $scope.id = 'city';
      $scope.attr = 'details';
      }    
    if ($scope.x == 'state') {
      $scope.id = 'state';
      $scope.attr = 'title';
    }
    if ($scope.x == 'country') {
      $scope.id = 'country';
      $scope.attr = 'name';
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I have read over your question multiple times and am a bit confused what you're asking.  Can you please provide more information and clarify your question.

Comment: I don't understand what do want to do

Comment: where ever no data found comes after on change any option,we need to hide the button,just change the options and see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess ng-if will be the optimum solution if you are already aware about the condition when to hide data, in your case 'No data'.
In your HTML you can add the condition

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
app.controller("myCtrl", function($scope) {
  $scope.groups = [{
      title: 'title1',
      name: 'name1',
      details: 'No data',
      id: 1
    },
    {
      title: 'title2',
      name: 'name2',
      details: 'two',
      id: 2
    },
    {
      title: 'title3',
      name: 'name2',
      details: 'three',
      id: 3
    }
  ]
  $scope.changeCss = function(input) {
    if (input === 'No data') {
      return {
        'color': 'red'
      }
    }
  }
  $scope.update = function() {
    if ($scope.x == 'city') {
      $scope.id = 'city';
      $scope.attr = 'details';
    }
    if ($scope.x == 'state') {
      $scope.id = 'state';
      $scope.attr = 'title';
    }
    if ($scope.x == 'country') {
      $scope.id = 'country';
      $scope.attr = 'name';
    }
  }

});
app.filter('modifydata', function() {
  return function(input) {
    if (input && input.length > 0) {
      if (input === 'No data')
        return 'No db found'
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.7.5/angular.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <select class="change" ng-model="x" ng-change="update()">
      <option value="city">Cities</option>
      <option value="state">States</option>
      <option value="country">Countries</option>
    </select>
    <div ng-repeat="emp in groups" class="test" ng-attr-id="{{emp[attr]}}">
      <p ng-style="changeCss(emp[attr])">{{emp[attr] | modifydata}}<button ng-if="emp[attr]!='No data'" type="button">My button</button></p>
      <!--place here in  the scope of ng-repeat-->
      <div ng-if="false" class="error">hello</div>
    </div>
    <!--<div ng-if="false" class="error">hello</div>-->
  </div>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer,I need to show manually a different div, <div ng-if="emp[attr]=='No data'">No db found</div> at the porting where showing 'No data',I tried above line of code but it was not working ,Can you please help me on it

Comment: @carreankush as you said you need to hide the button whenever 'No data' comes in the options and it works smooth for that. Please refer the code snipped for the same

Comment: That is working fine but I want to display a custom message 'No db found' in red color just nearby to 'no data' text.

Comment: @carreankush can refer the updated snipped for the conditions, do let me know if you face any issues

Comment: can you please upvote the previous solution, your conditions of code are getting complex and difficult to understand your requirement

Comment: ohh dear it was div tag you just closed before the ng-repeat div. Just updated the html in my answer, have a look